# How does France compare to other countries with respect to police brutality?

Tags: france, police, human-rights, comparative-politics

Recently France has seen some massive protests against  Macron’s pension law. Most of these protests are peaceful, but unavoidably there was some violence, especially since Macron decided to bypass the [parliament vote on the pension law](https://www.politico.eu/article/macron-invokes-nuclear-option-to-force-through-his-pensions-reform-in-huge-political-setback/), a decision perceived as authoritarian and against the will of the people. It's worth noting that there was violence on both sides, some from the police and some from some protesters.

There have been multiple incidents of police brutality (see e.g. [Guardian article](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2023/mar/25/french-police-accused-of-using-excessive-force-during-pension-protests), [video 1](https://www.nouvelobs.com/social/20230324.OBS71321/il-y-a-mon-grand-pere-par-terre-les-images-d-une-charge-policiere-dans-la-manifestation-du-23-mars-a-paris.html), [video 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u6jBBsIRxmk)). Police violence has always been an contentious issue in France; [in this article [fr]](https://basta.media/vendredi-debat-Anne-Sophie-Simpere-la-france-est-elle-la-mauvaise-eleve-europeenne-en-matiere-de-maintien-de-l-ordre-violences-policieres) (from a left-wing media), the author argues that there is at least a lack of will by the French institutions to try and change the police methods. Nevertheless the violence is critized internationally, with [European institutions](https://www.coe.int/fr/web/commissioner/view/-/asset_publisher/ugj3i6qSEkhZ/content/id/206875371?_com_liferay_asset_publisher_web_portlet_AssetPublisherPortlet_INSTANCE_ugj3i6qSEkhZ_languageId=en_GB#p_com_liferay_asset_publisher_web_portlet_AssetPublisherPortlet_INSTANCE_ugj3i6qSEkhZ) and [human rights NGOs [fr]](https://www.francetvinfo.fr/faits-divers/police/violences-policieres/video-violences-policieres-on-est-dans-une-situation-alarmante-pour-la-democratie-denonce-le-president-de-la-ligue-des-droits-de-l-homme_5725505.html) criticising abuses (in a sad irony, even [Iran critised France for police brutality](https://www.voanews.com/a/iran-condemns-france-for-repression-of-protests-/7020694.html)).

Protests are unavoidable in democratic countries, occasionally with some violence. In this context, is there any significant difference in terms of police methods between France and other similar countries?

Comment: Probably a better Q to ask is if there are objective metrics to compare police brutality between countries...

Comment: That question has already been asked https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/63911/how-can-i-compare-levels-of-police-violence-in-different-states-of-the-world?rq=1

Comment: Certainly anecdotal in nature, but while living in France in the 90s, it was common to see [CRS ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compagnies_R%C3%A9publicaines_de_S%C3%A9curit%C3%A9) platoon/squad sized detachments of riot police deployed at locations without any particular disturbances going on, merely sitting there "just in case".  These aren't regular police doing regular patrols.  And that seems at odd with other Western countries I've been in.

Comment: @JamesK the other question is related but hardly a duplicate: the question and answer are quantitative and the answer only proposes two very coarse indicators (with one not even considered useful by the author of the answer). By contrast my question is qualitative in nature, with specific examples and references related to police methods. Ideally I would like to find articles/analysis trying to answer the question. Another way to look at it would be to answer the question whether human rights organizations or the Council of Europe frequently warn other similar countries about this issue?

Comment: Maybe another way to approach this question is to ask whether the level of violence in current police suppression of the anti-reform protests is more violent than that seen in past French riot control.  i.e. to me, 2 different questions seem possible:  a) is French police generally more violent?  and b) is French police *under Macron* more violent?  b) seems a more pressing concern than a) and is certainly not a duplicate.  When you see widespread civil disturbances, along with riot control efforts, it is not unreasonable to ask if the riot control is disproportionate to the protests.

Comment: @erwan,  I agree, I said that Fizz's suggested alternative has already been asked. Altough that other question contains many of the basic elements of an answer, and you could, perhaps use it as a starting point for writing your answer.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: well, the French seemingly do like to protest more, at least in form of strikes https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/78741/why-does-industrial-actions-in-france-seem-to-happen-more-frequently-visibly-a And probably the "spirit of '68" and all that (at least going by what CGTN [says](https://news.cgtn.com/news/3455444d356b7a6333566d54/index.html), LOL.)

Comment: *"the author argues that there is at least a lack of will by the French institutions to try and change the police methods"* <<< Nice euphemism. Police brutality appears to have increased in the last few years, and in many cases it's pretty clear the police officers are following orders, not just acting on their own initiative.

Comment: Another thing that we can compare is the internal affairs department, from one country to the next. In other words: who examines your complaint if you complain against an act of police misconduct? In some countries, this is a department which is fully independent from the police. In other countries, it's a branch of the police, located inside a police building, and made up of police officers who use the same coffee machine as the police officers they're supposed to investigate.

Comment: I've known a French "activist" (protesting against expulsion of undocumented immigrants, for example) for over 20 years. She has visited the ER a few times, so police brutality isn't new in that sense, and CRS especially are not reknown for their finesse. I have no idea however how one would ever go about evaluating that. The activist I know, for example, never reported those acts, assuming that nothing would come out of it anyway, and I've seen a certain fatalism amongst protesters that if you're going to protest, you should be prepared for police brutality.

Comment: Are you asking specifically about police brutality in the context of a protest, or brutality across the board (like America's problem with police violence against black people).

Comment: @Barmar I think it's better to keep the question focused on the context of protests/crowd control because police brutality in general might be a bit too broad. But it's clearly related, so if there are any good study/stats about police brutality in general I think it might be relevant.

Comment: I think this question would greatly benefit from some sort of definition for brutality. Is tear gas brutality? Are rubber bullets? There is a line between justified enforcement and brutality. Crowd control measures for riot suppression can often appear brutal compared to individual enforcement tactics. Also, each country somewhat defines police brutality differently. If you don't want to use your own definition, then it would be helpful to cite an example study or perspective to use.

Comment: Worth noting that France has a much higher level of politically motivated violence than many comparable countries that the a lot of the allegations of violence are associated with "street politics" rather than with run of the mill criminal or suspected criminal activity.

Comment: @DavidS the tool used for crowd control is not brutal in itself. It's the way it's used that is brutal, and french police as an history of making an extensive use of these tools when it could have easily be avoided if the crowd control doctrines were not what they are.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few points that characterise French difference to other European countries

- Police’s method
- Use of peace enforcement weaponry

French police make an extensive use of [Kettling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kettling) which as been heavily contested as an efficient method. Many people claim it still used as a way to scare people and dissuade them from going to protests. During the latest pension protests, there have been claim that police [randomly arrested people](https://www.euronews.com/2023/03/21/france-protest-arrests-are-the-police-abusing-the-legal-system), again to dissuade them from protesting. (You can see in the linked article they even caught foreign teenagers students)

Since the early 2000s, France police have been updating its weaponry to more offensive means. The [LBD](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanceur_de_balles_de_d%C3%A9fense) (flash ball) have been widely popularised accros police’s units. This weapon has been widely criticised as it has been made responsible of critical wound that don’t match with the level of violence that was deploy by the target (protester). [Yellow vest protests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow_vests_protests) has been the turning point with a very extensive use of flash ball. Many case of use were litigious but the [IGPN](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inspection_g%C3%A9n%C3%A9rale_de_la_Police_nationale) (which is kind of the MP, but for French’s police) systematically disculped the involved policeman.

Those 2 things hands in hands leads to a higher level of violence, and are the two main things you won’t find in other European countries.

Other arguments would be the use of police by the established political power, it’s an open debate in France that the political power uses the police to suppress people’s will and it has no popular legitimacy if you remove the police (basically it only hold thanks to police’s brutality). Others think France is on the verge of civil war and that french people are lucky to have the police enforcing republican order against mainly far-left revolutionaries.

But this part of the answer depend on your political leaning so I will let you make your own opinion on the matter.

Comment: Other differences include the IGPN being part of the police, which explains why it tends to always disculpate the involved policemen. In the UK for instance, the bureau that investigates policemen is completely separate from the police, which leads to fairer investigations. Also, in recent years the government has been offering "gifts" to the police to buy their loyalty. The vaccine pass is an example: for quite a while, people who didn't have proof of covid vaccine shots were forbidden from entering restaurants and other public places, but police officers were exempt from that rule.

Answer (score 1):

### Assuming brutality is directly related to deaths*

Looking at [statistics on police killings by country](https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/police-killings-by-country) we can see France has a rate of **3.8** deaths per 10 million compared to surrounding european countries:

- Switzerland: 0 deaths
- Denmark: 0 deaths
- United Kingdom: **0.5** deaths per 10 million
- Portugal: **1.0** deaths per 10 million
- Sweden: **1.0** deaths per 10 million
- Germany: **1.3** deaths per 10 million
- Finland: **1.8** deaths per 10 million
- Norway: **1.9** deaths per 10 million
- Netherlands: **2.7** deaths per 10 million
- Belgium: **4.3** deaths per 10 million*

From this we can see that the rate of police killings are markedly higher in France compared to surrounding european democracies. Only Belgium sitting at a similar rate. It is worth noting that [the rate of protest is also higher in France](https://carnegieendowment.org/publications/interactive/protest-tracker) - with 20 recorded protests vs:

- Norway: 1
- Sweden: 2
- Netherlands: 3
- Portugal: 4
- Belgium: 5
- Germany: 8
- United Kingdom: 11

Where larger clashes are more likely to occur and police are likely to resort to harsher methods than in smaller incidents where the police may more easily control the situation. Please note this is not an attempt to blame the populous for protesting only noting how situations and methods may vary between countries.

It is also worth noting a direct comparison between countries assumes similar methods recording of deaths attributed to police action and honesty of the systems.

---

*Deaths leading from brutality obviously depend on methods, for this reason I've left the US out by comparison as their police have much easier access to more lethal means of enforcement. For reference, the US' rate is 28.54 deaths per 10 million citizens.

*Worth bearing in mind Belgium has a small population so the statistic is less generalised. France's 3.8 deaths per 10 million is actually 26 total killings whereas Belgium's is only 5 total killings.

Comment: Am I right to assume the unit is deaths per 10 million *per year*?

Comment: *"Where larger clashes are more likely to occur and police are likely to resort to harsher methods than in smaller incidents where the police may more easily control the situation."* Except that in many cases the situation was *already under control*, i.e. the protests were peaceful, but then the police attacked and that's how the situation got out of control.

Comment: @Stef Yep it is per year. The mention of protests is just pointing out that there is a different balance for comparing countries, not trying to say who started it. Police at a protest are likely to be equipped with harsher deterrents than those on patrol - riot gear for one - and so the likelihood of police brutality ending in death is higher.

Comment: Most death, if not all, don't occur in protests. But in the other hand, these deaths can cause protests (see latest protests, after Nahel's death). As the main question was about police brutality in protests, I don't think it's a good metric.

It's 2 different cases. Death caused by police are usually a lone policeman that used his service weapon to act in self defence (some can argue that in many cases it's made in an abusive way, and against racial minorities). Police brutality in protests are more structural in the way that the whole hierarchy consent to it

Answer (score -3):

Many countries, both democratic and authoritarian, often use police brutality to enforce order. However a crucial difference is that authoritarian countries use police brutality to crush any possible dissent and instil fear into the poplace. Authoritarian examples include China and Russia who have used police brutality to crush protests. This is different to France as such who are not doing it to crush dissent but rather enforce order. Police brutality of course should be avoided at all costs but in democratic countries like France the purpose of the police brutality is different to that of authoritarian regimes.

Comment: I agree that this is an important point, but it doesn't really answer the question: how does France compare to other non-authoritarian countries? For example the police uses a wider range of weapons than other European countries. There are even people in France who think that the police was actually instructed to act harshly in order to discourage the protests.

Comment: @Erwan It does partly answer the question regarding differences differences in police methods between France and authoritarian countries. Answer can be improved though with more comparison with other non-authoritarian countries.

Comment: No, this really isn't what I had in mind on the bounty either.  How does France compare to its *democratic* peers in violence by riot police?  For example, many studies and articles compare the use of lethal force by US police.  The implicit question there is how does the US compare to *democratic* countries.  No one wants a strawman argument saying "no, our police and legal systems are just fine cuz look at Russia or China".  Note "*other similar countries?*" at the end of the question.

Comment: After reading the question and this answer, I, too, feel this doesn't answer the question in the sense of comparing something like "the degree of police violence" between France and (preferrably politically similar) other countries. At the same time, as an answer to the (also somewhat possible) interpretation to compare "the overall rationale/reasons for police violence", this answer would have to dig deeper. At least I think public statements from the listed authoritarian examples time and again do justify certain police action as nothing but a rightful way to "enforce order".